error in the application's ajax request in an azure app
I have an app in python-django and on localhost everything works normally. I make ajax requests to Python correctly, however it doesn't work in the Azure application, follow the example code of how I make a request:
 $.ajax({
                url: '/PlanEx/DCC/GerarTabelaAnova',
                data: formData,
                type: 'POST',

Furthermore, my gateway app constantly times out

What do the logs show?

If possible, can you share your repo?

Given info is not enough for us to debug the problem. You should post error log, what you did, settings.py, relevant views, urls ect. Otherwise how can someone help you?

I tried deploying a simple Django project, which includes an AJAX POST request, to Azure App Service without any issues.
This is my project structure
ajax_project/
├── ajax_example/
│   ├── migrations/
│   ├── templates/
│   │   └── ajax_example_post.html
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py                 
│   └── views.py
├── ajax_project/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt

ajax_example/views.py:
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt 

def ajax_post_page(request):
    return render(request, 'ajax_example_post.html')

@csrf_exempt
def ajax_post_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get('data', '')
        
        response_data = {'received_data': data}
        
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Only POST requests are allowed'})

ajax_example/urls.py:
from  django.urls  import  path
from .views  import  ajax_post_view, ajax_post_page
urlpatterns  = [
path('ajax-post/', ajax_post_view, name='ajax_post_view'),
path('ajax-post-page/', ajax_post_page, name='ajax_post_page'),
]

ajax_example_post.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AJAX POST Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="send-post">Send POST Request</button>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#send-post').click(function() {
                var dataToSend = {'key': 'value'};  // JSON data to send
                var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken'); 
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ajax/ajax-post/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken 
                    },
                    data: dataToSend,
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log('Response:', response);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

ajax_project/urls.py:
from  django.urls  import  path, include
from  ajax_example.views  import  ajax_post_page 
urlpatterns  = [
path('', ajax_post_page), 
path('ajax/', include('ajax_example.urls')),
]

Settings.py:
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-lmn9zwrj2x99-*y$%l-4dl%*e)dyy=g#d%-_0ee&mq-#@)cl4)'
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS =['127.0.0.1', 'sdjangoajax.azurewebsites.net'
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'ajax_project.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'ajax_example' / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ajax_project.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

Create a requirements.txt file before deploying your app to azure app service
To generate a requirements.txt file, you can use the following command in your terminal.
pip freeze > requirements.txt

Local output:

Here's the output after deployment:

